# Bayesian Chain rule

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayesian, naive-bayes

I am going thorugh a Naive Bayes Classifier, and faced the following:

$p(y|a,b,c) = \frac{p(a|y,b)*p(y|c)}{p(a|b,c)}$

When I am trying to derive the above, these are my steps:

$p(y|a,b,c)=\frac{p(y,a,b,c)}{p(a,b,c)}=\frac{p(a|y,b,c)*p(y|b,c)*p(b|c)*p(c)}{p(a|b,c)*p(b|c)*p(c)}$

Which leads to:
$\frac{p(a|y,b,c)*p(y|b,c)}{p(a|b,c)}$

My question is how to prove the above derivation. Where $y$ is category and it is described by Dirichlet parameters of $\theta$, and $a$ is another category is described by dirichlet parameter vector $c$.

Comment: Your derivation is correct. This means that the probability of $a$ given $y$ and $b$ must be independent of $c$, and the probability of $y$ given $c$ is independent of $b$. Does this make sense in your case?

Comment: Oops! I just figured it out. Sorry inattention in my part!! Thanks for the note anyway!